# Why doesn't this simple python multiprocessing script parallelize better after 2 cores?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, multiprocessing

I'm trying to parallelize some code of mine on AWS EC2 instances using python's multiprocessing module. However, I'm not getting the speedup I was expecting. Since I'm not sure what the problem is, I tried running this simple example script below.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def square(x):
    result = x**2

    return result

def par():
    for num_cores in range(1,multiprocessing.cpu_count()+1):

        start = time.time()
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_cores)
        x = range(0,1000000)

        results = pool.map(square,x)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        stop = time.time()
        print num_cores,stop-start

if __name__=='__main__':
    par()
```

I ran this on a c4.8xlarge EC2 instance (36 vCPUs), and got output that improves from num_core=1 to num_core=2, but pretty much saturates after that point. This is the same behavior I see with my actual code (which is more complicated). Did I do something incorrect in the script (work I did a year ago done similarly worked fine on EC2), or is there something specific about the EC2 instances that would result in this behavior?

The output looks something like this:

```
1 4.54366803169
2 2.94242286682
3 2.8423769474
4 2.62595009804
5 2.57699894905
6 2.73259091377
7 2.59096288681
8 2.64281415939
9 2.63401508331
10 2.68470692635
11 3.24949598312
12 2.57163906097
13 2.72224593163
14 2.53613996506
15 2.50157499313
16 2.58340406418
17 2.50496888161
18 2.56644797325
19 2.59975194931
20 2.59667301178
21 2.7128059864
22 2.73017811775
23 2.59903597832
24 2.64776611328
25 2.62305593491
26 2.70264601707
27 2.66796994209
28 2.62165784836
29 2.73838996887
30 2.67824697495
31 2.67478704453
32 2.74541497231
33 2.72921586037
34 2.69398999214
35 2.77073812485
36 2.77028203011
```

Comment: Consider a slightly more expensive operation.  The limiting factor here is likely the thread that's sending off & collecting the results.

Comment: I agree with @SeanMcSomething. Also, be wary of any hyper-threading the machine might be doing. Not sure how many physical cores it has, but that should be the highest you go.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething, you may be correct. I modified the square function to be instead 'result = math.log(x) * x**2 + 3*x + math.log(2*x)'. In doing so I didn't see output saturation until core 7 or 8. So perhaps something similar is going on with my actual code.